# Access pandas column data with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I am newish to Pandas and attempting to group a dataframe (loaded from excel file), then loop through each unique groups data and perform additional operations on it.  For this example, let's just say access and print the column data in the group df.

Example table data

| id | color | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | 20 |
| 1 | Red | 25 |
| 1 | Blue | 20 |
| 1 | Blue | 15 |
| 1 | Green | 5 |
| 2 | Red | 100 |
| 2 | Blue | 20 |
| 2 | Blue | 220 |
| 2 | Blue | 120 |
| 2 | Blue | 20 |
| 2 | Green | 220 |
| 2 | Green | 120 |
| 2 | Green | 45 |
| 2 | Green | 2 |
| 2 | Green | 5 |

My initial code

```
df = pd.read_excel(test.xlsx')
grouped = df.grouby(['id'])

for key, values in grouped.groups.items():
     print("keys: {}".format(key))
     print("values: {}".format(values))
```

I want to perform the follow operations:

1. Loop through each group ("id")
2. For each, "id", loop through each color and print out the value of each instance of color within that group.

I'm struggling with how to loop through the each group ('id') and access each of the grouped column data.  I have tried the above code just to learn what iterating the group looks like.

Answer (score 1):

This basically prints out the entire table, but I am not sure how you want to structure the printing of the subgroups.

But it may help you anyhow

```py
for name, group in df.groupby("id"):
    print("id", name)
    for idx, row in group.iterrows():
        print("\trow index", idx, "color", row.color, "value", row.value)
```

Prints

```
id 1
    row index 0 color Red value 20
    row index 1 color Red value 25
    row index 2 color Blue value 20
    row index 3 color Blue value 15
    row index 4 color Green value 5
id 2
    row index 5 color Red value 100
    row index 6 color Blue value 20
    row index 7 color Blue value 220
    row index 8 color Blue value 120
    row index 9 color Blue value 20
    row index 10 color Green value 220
    row index 11 color Green value 120
    row index 12 color Green value 45
    row index 13 color Green value 2
    row index 14 color Green value 5
```

---

Edit:

```py
for name, group in df.groupby("id"):
    print("id", name)
    for color, subgroup in group.groupby("color"):
        print("\t", color, list(subgroup["value"]))
```

gives

```
id 1
     Blue [20, 15]
     Green [5]
     Red [20, 25]
id 2
     Blue [20, 220, 120, 20]
     Green [220, 120, 45, 2, 5]
     Red [100]
```

Are you looking for that?

Comment: Thanks.  I would like each color:value pair within the each id separated

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('test.csv.xlsx')

id_list = list(data['id'].unique())
color_list = list(data['color'].unique())

for i in id_list :
    for j in color_list :
    count = (data['color'][(data['color'] == j) & (data['id'] == i )]).count()
    print (f"The count of {j} in ID {i} is equal to {count}")
```

Output:

```
The count of Red in ID 1 is equal to 2 
The count of Blue in ID 1 is equal to 2
The count of Green in ID 1 is equal to 1
The count of Red in ID 2 is equal to 1
The count of Blue in ID 2 is equal to 4
The count of Green in ID 2 is equal to 5
```